# Overloading ?? operator with Result type

Tags: swift

I'm reading the [Functional Swift book](https://www.objc.io/books/functional-swift/) and to demonstrate Optionals, Chapter 8 mentions how `??` operator could be defined to work on Result type, a previously defined type. However, when I attempt to utilize this operator, I don't see the overloaded version getting invoked. Am I using this operator incorrectly?

```
// Define ErrorType
enum LookupError: ErrorType {
    case CapitalNotFound
    case PopulationNotFound
}

enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(ErrorType)
}

// Overloaded operator
func ??<T>(result: Result<T>, handleError: ErrorType -> T) -> T {
    print("overloaded result: \(result)")
    switch result {
    case let .Success(value): return value
    case let .Error(error): return handleError(error)
    }
}
```

I'm utilizing the operator like this:

```
let r:Result<String>? = Result<String>.Success("A-Ok")
let d = Result<String>.Success("Error")
let result = r ?? d
```

Doing this shows:

```
Result: Success("A-Ok")
```

But at no point does the overloaded operator get invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expression `let result = r ?? d` does not match the function signature of your overload, and hence it doesn't know that it's your function that you want to call (and calls the regular nil coalescing operator instead).

Let's take a look at the signature:

```
func ??<T>(result: Result<T>, handleError: ErrorType -> T) -> T { ...
```

You use the first argument in your call almost correctly, it should be of type `Result<T>`, however not an optional. The 2nd parameter in your custom `??` function, however, is a *closure*, a function taking type `ErrorType` and returning generic `T` (in our example: `String`), and the second argument in your call must be of such a closure type. Hence, your two `Result<String>` instances `r` and `d` should not be used together with your custom `??` operator, but on their own together with the appropriate closure.

Define your two example instances of `Result<String>`---one containing an error and one containing a success---as

```
var r:Result<String> = Result<String>.Success("A-Ok")
var d:Result<String> = Result<String>.Error(LookupError.CapitalNotFound)
```

Now, to conform to your `??` function signature in our calls to it, we construct the right hand side of your expression to be a closure as follows:

```
var result = r ?? {
    err in
        switch err as! LookupError {
        case .CapitalNotFound: return "Couldn't find capital"
        case .PopulationNotFound: return "Couldn't find population"
        }
    }
print(result) /* A-Ok */

result = d ?? {
    err in
    switch err as! LookupError {
    case .CapitalNotFound: return "Couldn't find capital"
    case .PopulationNotFound: return "Couldn't find population"
    }
}
print(result) /* Couldn't find capital */
```

Ok, now we actually call your `??` overload. These expressions above, however, looks quite messy, especially if we want to call our custom `??` operator frequently.

Instead of posting the same closure each time you perform your error check, we can create a handle to the closure that we make use of instead. The handle is used---just like the closure above---as the right hand side argument in the call to your custom `??` operator:

```
func myStringErrHandler () -> (ErrorType -> String) {
    return { (err: ErrorType) -> (String) in
        switch err as! LookupError {
        case .CapitalNotFound: return "Couldn't find capital"
        case .PopulationNotFound: return "Couldn't find population"
    }
}
let errHandle = myStringErrHandler()

var result = r ?? errHandle
print(result) /* A-Ok */

result = d ?? errHandle
print(result) /* Couldn't find capital */
```

This could probably be done even neater, but you get the gist of it: we must make sure our call and its arguments conform to the signature of our custom function.

Comment: I was thrown off by looking at Swift's definition for the nil coalescing operator, which is defined like this: 

public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T

The defaultValue parameter looked like it was taking a function without any arguments, returning a value of type T.  Since the Swift lang version didn't take a function, I assumed that the above version also wouldn't.

Comment: You are right that also for the native `??` case is the second argument a closure, even if it *seemingly* can be used as if it was a single parameter of type `T`. The key here is the keyword `@autoclosure`, which allows a closure function parameter _with no parameters of its own_ to be sent as an argument to the function without being wrapped in `{...}`. Hence, in native `??`, `rhs` in `lhs ?? rhs` actually describes the return statement for the closure `() -> T` (you can think of it as `lhs ?? { return rhs }`). The reason for this is that we can lazily evaluate `rhs` (as it is a closure) ...

Comment: ... because the actual value of `rhs` (return value of closure) will only be "evaluated" in function `??` if we choose it to be: and we only want it to be so in case `lhs` contains `nil`. Hence (error throwing aside), for the case of native `??`, we could as well define 2nd parameter as a standard single variable parameter, but then there would be no lazy evaluation of, which would be wasteful in case we never reach the right hand side of the nil coalescing expression. A little outdated post, but still useful for learning, see: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4

Answer (score 0):

Your `r` is a `Result` wrapped in an `Optional`, so you get the version of the `??` operator that applies to optionals.

Since you're not making use of optionality in your example, you need only fix the declaration:

```
let r:Result<String> = Result<String>.Success("A-Ok")
let d = Result<String>.Success("Error")
let result = r ?? d
```

Comment: `d` here doesn't comply to the expected `ErrorType -> String` closure, the 2nd argument (rhs) in the custom `??` function. Hence, this will not call the custom `??` function.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I only got as far as the problem with the first parameter's type, but one needs to fix both sides.